# cannot borrow `win` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable

Tags: rust, reference, immutability, mutable, borrow-checker

I am getting a cannot borrow `win` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
as the commented line

```rust
let (mut win, thread) = raylib::init().size(800, 600).title("Demo").build();
// error at borrowing win
draw.draw_rectangle(
            // here
            win.get_screen_width() / 2,
            0,
            5,
            // and here
            win.get_screen_height(),
            Color::WHITE,
);
```

Comment: can you please share the error message as well

Comment: The example is incomplete. What's `draw`, and what version of `raylib` are you using?

Comment: You need to provide more information. A [reprex] will give people a chance of helping you.

Comment: But, making a lot of guesses about the rest of your code, you can probably fix this by introducing new variables, `width` and `height` before the method call, rather than doing it all inline.

Comment: The code you are showing does not contain the actual problem. [`win.get_screen_width()`](https://docs.rs/raylib/latest/raylib/core/struct.RaylibHandle.html#method.get_screen_width) is an immutable borrow, and so is [`win.get_screen_height()`](https://docs.rs/raylib/latest/raylib/core/struct.RaylibHandle.html#method.get_screen_height). This should compile fine. The actual error comes from code you don't show here. I agree with @PeterHall, please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are two possibility (you do not provide enough ressources to test it in my workspace so it is just supposition) :

Save length before calling :

```
let (mut win, thread) = raylib::init().size(800, 600).title("Demo").build();
let width = win.get_screen_width() / 2;
let height = win.get_screen_height();
draw.draw_rectangle(width, 0, 5, height, Color::WHITE);
```

Or you could just clone your instance :

```
let (mut win, thread) = raylib::init().size(800, 600).title("Demo").build();
draw.draw_rectangle(win.clone().get_screen_width() / 2, 0, 5, win.clone().get_screen_height(), Color::WHITE);
```

Hope this help (and works ^^')

Comment: OP really needs to add more information before this can be answered. This solution is unlikely to work because the error suggests that `draw_rectangle` takes `&mut self` and that `draw` must hold a mutable reference to `win` too. In that case you would have to introduce the width and height variables _before_ `draw` was assigned.

Comment: This worked after destructuring my code for getting width and height into variables

```rust
let (mut win, thread) = raylib::init().size(800, 600).title("Demo").build();
let win_width = win.get_screen_width();
let win_height = win.get_screen_height();
// then while calling draw
draw.draw_rectangle(win_width / 2, 0, 5, win_height, Color::WHITE);
```